# Android: why my viewModel is not updated when I edit my editText which is bound to using dataBinding

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I have the following viewModel declared in my fragment :

```
class NoteDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit  var noteDetailsViewModel:NoteDetailsViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNoteDetailsBinding



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val application= requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val args=NoteDetailsFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
        val noteDetailsViewModelFactory=NoteDetailsViewModelFactory(application,args.noteId)
        noteDetailsViewModel=ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(),noteDetailsViewModelFactory).get(NoteDetailsViewModel::class.java)



    }
```

and I have a onOptionItemSelected menu where I want to update my viewModel as the following :

```
  android.R.id.home -> {
                    noteDetailsViewModel.saveNote()
                    findNavController().navigateUp()

                    true

                }
```

my issue is that my viewModel is not update when the user update the xml layout here you can see my viewModel code to update

```
fun saveNote() {

        if (titleEditText.value.isNullOrEmpty() || descriptionEditText.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {

        } else {
            updateNote()
            viewModelScope.launch {
                if (noteIdentifier == null) {
                    repository.insertNote(editableNote)
                } else {
                    repository.updateNote(editableNote)
                }

            }
        }
    }
 fun updateNote() {
        editableNote.apply {
            title = titleEditText.value!!
            Log.i(TAG,"The title is $title")
            description = descriptionEditText.value!!
   
        }
    }
```

titleEditText and descriptionEditText are mutableLiveData and I am using databinding to set the in xml layout I have no idea why my updateNote function is not updating the editableNote Object with the latest value from the UI

here is my binding code:

```
 binding = FragmentNoteDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)




        binding.lifecycleOwner=this
        binding.viewModel=noteDetailsViewModel
```

and you can also check my layout

```
  <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.reminderapp.ui.notedetails.NoteDetailsViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/app_background_color"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
.......
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/note_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_view_margin"
            android:text="@{viewModel.titleEditText}"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/enter_title"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
...
```

Comment: Can you show your "Binding" code. Because you have to set it up properly. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @StefMa I updated the question with binding code

Comment: have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two-way databinding for this. Try this android:text="@={viewModel.titleEditText}"  instead of this android:text="@{viewModel.titleEditText. Also you should write @InverseBindingAdapter to make this work. See documentation for two-way databinding.